# опять проблемы с MySQL

Tags: mysql, debian

Отказывается Запускаться

mysql start

```
Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

systemctl status mysql.service

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-01 16:45:55 MSK; 1min 19s ago
  Process: 32531 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 01 16:45:24 comp.name systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
Mar 01 16:45:24 comp.name mysql[32531]: /etc/init.d/mysql: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz ... (warning).
Mar 01 16:45:24 comp.name /etc/init.d/mysql[32540]: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name /etc/init.d/mysql[555]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name /etc/init.d/mysql[555]: [61B blob data]
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name /etc/init.d/mysql[555]: error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name /etc/init.d/mysql[555]: Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name /etc/init.d/mysql[555]:
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name mysql[32531]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Mar 01 16:45:55 comp.name systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
root@borisowa:/etc/mysql# mysql start
Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Подскажите решение :) .... заранеее спасибо за пинки в нужную сторону

Comment: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz` Смотрите кому принадлежит и права. И почитайте README.Debian

Answer (score 1):

Вот в чем причина: Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored. Очень похоже на то, что читать и писать в этот файл может каждый (read/write by others). Поэтому mysql его и игнорирует. Надо у него(others) эти права убрать.